# How to test AWS SNS locally?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, localhost

I want to use `Amazon SNS service`. And I want to have an ability to subscribe an *http rest to SNS* topic to receive notifications.

However locally my application has URL as `localhost` So it's impossible for me to test application behavior locally.

I found one article about using `ngrok` server, to use some public IP instead of local.

However it doesn't seem to be a good solution for me.

Do you have any ideas how I could have a working *SNS subscriber locally?*

Answer (score 23):

You could also use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your localhost publicly.

They way it works is it creates a subdomain dynamically and tunnels all request to your machine on the desired port.

Picture this scenario, I have a nginx running on localhost:8080.
I open my terminal and run `ngrok 8080`, it will take my terminal session and log my public url, like 'as78fh.ngrok.com'.

If I go on another computer, open the browser and navigate to as78fh.ngrok.com/register the request gets served from my localhost:8080/register through the tunnel back to the internet.

I use it for lots of tricky developments, like email webhooks, github integrations and, of course, amazon sns.

Comment: I've used ngrok and I exposed my webservice using it, I created a subscription in my AWS SNS and unfortunately, I didn't get the confirmation message! Do you know what might cause that?

Comment: Hey, visit 127.0.0.1:4040 and check if the message is reaching your endpoint at all. If it is, the problem is probably code, if the message isnt reaching your tunnel, try resending the confirmation using the sns pannel

Comment: Yeah, I can see that the message is reaching my tunnel, but I don't know why the code of the endpoint is not executed.

Comment: well, the good thing is that it's all on your machine now! check if the url is matching, if it's returning 200. One thing I like to do when that happens is to return a response on the first line, just to check the full flow!

Comment: I'm trying to call the webservice I've implemented locally using the pattern of: https://admin:admin@blablabla.ngrok.io/api/core/v3/sns and it's working but the weird thing is that when aws sns calls my webservice the response code is 401.

Comment: maybe ngrok is not forwarding the username and pass, but I'd advise that instead of using this method for the authentication, you could leave the enpoint public and just check the sns message signature!
Here's the relevant link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.verify.signature.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at one of fake SNS implementations in GitHub, such as [s12v/sns](https://github.com/s12v/sns):

> Fake Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) for testing. Supports:
>
> - Create/List/Delete topics
> - Subscribe endpoint
> - Publish message
> - Subscription persistence
> - Integrations with (Fake-)SQS, File, HTTP, RabbitMQ, Slack

Comment: It seems it doesn't work with the latest sdk.  

AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("localhost:9911", "us-east-1");
        AmazonSNS amazonSNSClient = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
                .build();
        System.out.println(amazonSNSClient.listTopics());  
If I run a simple code - I got an error:  
Exception in thread "main" SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Answer (score 0):

I like ngrok but you pay to have a fixed external address, if you want to do it for free you could use a spare email account inbox to send Email-JSON sns. Then an IMAP library to access it, read the emails and pipe the data.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small [library](https://github.com/gilbertojrequena/bonsai-sns) that mimics AWS SNS and I think it fits to your needs. Here is an example of the usage in Java:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSAsyncClientBuilder;
import io.github.gilbertojrequena.bonsai_sns.server.BonsaiSnsEnvironment;
import io.github.gilbertojrequena.bonsai_sns.server.BonsaiSnsServer;
import io.github.gilbertojrequena.bonsai_sns.server.Subscription;
import io.github.gilbertojrequena.bonsai_sns.server.Topic;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SNSTest {

    private BonsaiSnsServer server;
    private AmazonSNS snsClient;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // start your app at 8080

        server = new BonsaiSnsServer.Builder()
            .withAccountId(123456789L)
            .withPort(7979)
            .withRegion("someRegion")
            .withBonsaiSnsEnvironmentDefinition(
                BonsaiSnsEnvironment.Companion.definition()
                    .withTopic(
                        Topic.Companion.definition()
                            .withName("name")
                            .withSubscription(
                                Subscription.Companion.definition()
                                    .withEndpoint("http:/localhost:8080/endpoint")
                                    .withProtocol("http")
                                    .withAttribute("a", "b")
                            )
                    )
            ).start();

        snsClient = AmazonSNSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey")))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:7979", "someRegion"))
            .build();
    }

    @After
    public void shutdown() {
        server.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        snsClient.publish("arn:aws:sns:someRegion:123456789:name", "message");
        // assertions
    }
}
```