# AWS SNS to notify a locally-running CLI application

Tags: amazon-sns

AWS SNS can push to http, email, SMS, lambda, "device and mobile application".

Is there a way to get it to push to a locally-running CLI application?

I can imagine that maybe it is possible to register an EC2 server as a "device" and the CLI as the "mobile application". Couldn't figure out any docs about this.

Edit: or perhaps register an EC2 server as IoT and push sns to IoT device?

Comment: What is a "locally-running CLI application"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it's a python command-line application

Answer (score 0):

No. Sort of.

Amazon SNS needs to send a message to "somewhere" that wants to receive the message. So, you could run a web server that is Internet-accessible and SNS will send the message via HTTP to that endpoint.

Mobile applications also have endpoints provided by Apple/Google/Baidu that will then forward messages to a mobile device. So, they are also listening for a message.

**Bottom line:** You need something that is listening for a message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for this. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45406592/4523373) should solve your question perfectly.

Comment: This indeed is one way to go about it. I was wondering if there is another more direct way that didn't involve starting up a new http listener. But you make a good point.

Comment: The only other way that you can achieve this is by mocking the SNS service. Check out [localstack](https://gugsrs.com/localstack-sqs-sns) and [Fake AWS SNS](https://github.com/s12v/sns)